# The property of a module that has a simple socle

Tags: representation-theory, socle

Let M be a module that has a simple socle.I can get that M is indecomposable and all submodules of M contain socM. Are there any other properties of M? Can we character the structure of M? And is M/socM also indecomposable?

Comment: Pretty much no to all the questions. Modules with simple socles come in all sorts, and that quotient need not be indecomposable.

Comment: If M is a finite dimensional module of a finite dimensional K-algebra,then can the answers be better?